# Why curl doesn't work with my active session?

Tags: php, web, curl

I have issue with my feature which I want add to my website.

When I'm trying exec curl, script  getting crash (HTTP ERROR 500).

There is something what I don't know about session and curl?

**Everything works without session OR withour execute curl.**

How I can fix that or where I should look to issue?

```
<?php 
session_start();

include("include/function.php");

if($_SESSION['logadm']=="adm" or $_SESSION['logmod']=="mod")
{

$link = $_GET['link'];
    $curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/keyyy");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array("content" => "$link", "username" => "webhook")));

curl_exec($curl)

}



header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");


?>
```

Comment: Check your error logs or enable error reporting. Something should be yelling at you. I don't know if this will solve your issue but you are using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` wrong unless the discordapp explicitly stated that's how you should send POST data.

Comment: Additionally, **Everything *"works"* without session OR withour execute curl** because without session your curl is never executed.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus "your curl is never executed." , of course he is.

Comment: Look at your server logs. If that doesn't help, look into turning on debug output for curl.